# ee.Algorithm.EEFlux Evapotranspiration (ET) Landsat Google Earth Engine

Tags: landsat, google-earth-engine

Does anyone know how to use ee.Algorithm.EEFux in Google Earth Engine to calculate Evapotranspiration with Landsat Images?

I am trying to use it but GEE does not recognise the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of January 2018, the [EEFlux evapotranspiration algorithms](https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Allen_UNL_DRI_UI_EEFlux_update_LST_meeting_July_8_2015c.pdf) are actively being developed by several academic research groups, and are not publicly accessible as Earth Engine algorithms.

Comment: unfortunately, the link doesn't work now. Here I found someone asked similar questions on researchgate: https://www.researchgate.net/post/is_google_eeflux_evapotranspiration_is_correct